# SpinifexIT - Easy Reporter write to FTP

Tags: ftp, sap-hr

Does anyone know how to enable or set-up spinifexIT easy reporter to write a scheduled reports data to an FTP. I cannot get it to work.

We set-up all connections and passwords in the spinifexIT easy reporter tool, however it doesn't write the file.

If anyone has any suggestions, it would be greatly apprecaited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy Reporter should work find with FTP server.  I'm not sure if you have been able to log into our helpdesk, but there is an article that gives some further advice - https://spinifexit.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024023654-Using-SFTP-to-Send-Files-from-Easy-Reporter

Alternatively, we would be happy to take a look at your setup if you like.  In order to do this, you can raise a support call to (support@spinifexit.com)

All the best, Darren Souter
Solution Architect Easy Suite Solutions